# How can I prevent hostname from changing?

Tags: macos, network, dns

When I boot up one of our computers it gets a static DHCP address which is specified in our DNS as client1.domain.com and so on. The hostname sets automatically from reverse DNS at bootup and everything work fine. But after a while I see that the computer changes hostname to Users-MacBook-Pro.local.

Our system depends on that the computers have a static hostname so I want to prevent the computer to change it by itself. It works if I manually set it using 'scutil' but I would just like to "lock" hostname to the one it is getting from the DNS.

Is there any way so accomplish that?

We are using OS X 10.9.5

Comment: Yes I know that. But it is about scripting a few things. We have about 100 Macs and they all have the correct hostname at bootup. That is when I would like to just lock to the current hostname.

Comment: is this all AFP or do you have SMB in the mix?

Comment: No filesharing at all. Our system depends on hostnames to be able to push out updates via Puppet. When the hostname changes, the certificate is no longer valid, until you reboot or set the hostname manually via scutil.